# PHP If Statement not working correctly, not null

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm struggling to understand why my if statement below always results in false. I am creating a function which will test incoming connections to a script which will reject connections made by certain bots.

In my test below, on applying the if logic, I'm expecting a TRUE as both the array `$value` and `$test` value should match... resulting in a NOT NULL?

```
$bots = array(0 => "PaperLiBot", 1 => "TweetmemeBot", 2 => "Appsfirebot", 3 => "PycURL", 4 => "JS-Kit", 5 => "Python-urllib");

$test = strtolower("PaperLiBot");


foreach($bots as $value)
{   
    $i = strtolower(strpos($value, $test));

    if ($i != NULL)
    {
        echo "Bot is found";
        exit;
    }else
    {
        echo "not found";
    }

}
```

Comment: `strotolower(strpos())` makes no sense. `strpos()` returns the position as an integer, or `false`. Did you mean it to say `strtolower($value)`?

Comment: Remove strtolower and check false !== $i ;)

Comment: thanks all for your feedback.

Comment: BTW, if you want contiguous numeric keys starting at 0 (0, 1, 2, ...) in your array you can omit them: `array("PaperLiBot", "TweetmemeBot", "Appsfirebot", "PycURL", "JS-Kit", "Python-urllib")`

Comment: @David thanks, that'll be easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are trying to accomplish this

```
foreach($bots as $value)
{   
    $i = strpos(strtolower($value), $test);

    if ($i !== false){
        echo "Bot is found";
        exit;
    }else{
        echo "not found";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you want to write:

```
if(stristr($value, $test)){
 // found
}else{
 // not found

}
```

Comment: That is incorrect if the position is 0 the if statement will fail.

Answer (score 0):

null in PHP is mutually type-castable to '0', '', ' ', etc... You need to use the strict comparisons to check for a 0-based array index:

```
if ($i !== NULL) { 
 ...
}
```

note the extra `=` in the inequality operator. It forces PHP to compare type AND value, not just value. When comparing value, PHP will typecast however it wants to in order to make the test work, which means `null == 0` is true, but `null === 0` is false.

Comment: strpos returns false, not null ;)

Comment: true, but OP is explicitly checking for null for some reason.

Comment: I was looking for null by mistake. Changed to False which now works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the correct way to check if a variable is set to NULL is:

```
if(!is_null($var)){
    [my code]
}
```

the strpos returns a boolean, not a NULL value.

if you are unsure of the content of a variable, you can always debug it with a simple

```
var_dump($var);
```